# Optimizing algorithm for matching duplicates

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, block, duplicates

I've written a small utility program that identifies duplicate tracks in iTunes. 
The actual matching of tracks takes a long time, and I'd like to optimize it.
I am storing track data in an NSMutableDictionary that stores individual track data in
NSMutableDictionaries keyed by trackID. These individual track dictionaries have 
at least the following keys:

- TrackID
- Name
- Artist
- Duration (in milli ####.####)

To determine if any tracks match one another, I must check:

- If the duration of two tracks are within 5 seconds of each other
- Name matches
- Artist matches

The slow way for me to do it is using two for-loops:

```
-(void)findDuplicateTracks {

    NSArray *allTracks = [tracks allValues];

    BOOL isMatch = NO;

    int numMatches = 0;

    // outer loop

    NSMutableDictionary *track      = nil;
    NSMutableDictionary *otherTrack = nil;

    for (int i = 0; i < [allTracks count]; i++) { 

        track = [allTracks objectAtIndex:i];

        NSDictionary *summary = nil;

        if (![claimedTracks containsObject:track]) {

            NSAutoreleasePool *aPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

            NSUInteger duration1  = (NSUInteger) [track objectForKey:kTotalTime];
            NSString *nName       = [track objectForKey:knName];
            NSString *nArtist     = [track objectForKey:knArtist];


            // inner loop - no need to check tracks that have
            // already appeared in i

            for (int j = i + 1; j < [allTracks count]; j++) { 

                otherTrack = [allTracks objectAtIndex:j];

                if (![claimedTracks containsObject:otherTrack]) {

                    NSUInteger duration2 = (NSUInteger)[otherTrack objectForKey:kTotalTime];

                    // duration check
                    isMatch = (abs(duration1 - duration2) < kDurationThreshold);

                    // match name
                    if (isMatch) {

                        NSString *onName = [otherTrack objectForKey:knName];

                        isMatch = [nName isEqualToString:onName];
                    }

                    // match artist
                    if (isMatch) {

                        NSString *onArtist = [otherTrack objectForKey:knArtist];

                        isMatch = [nArtist isEqualToString:onArtist];

                    }

                    // save match data
                    if (isMatch) {

                        ++numMatches;

                        // claim both tracks
                        [claimedTracks addObject:track];
                        [claimedTracks addObject:otherTrack];

                        if (![summary isMemberOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

                            [track setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"willDelete"];
                            summary = [self dictionarySummaryForTrack:track];

                        }


                        [otherTrack setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"willDelete"];                        
                        [[summary objectForKey:kMatches] 
                                            addObject:otherTrack];

                    }
                }
            }

            [aPool drain];
        }
    }
}
```

This becomes quite slow for large music libraries, and only uses 1
processor.  One recommended optimization was to use blocks and process
the tracks in batches (of 100 tracks). I tried that.  If my code
originally took 9 hours to run, it now takes about 2 hours on a
quad-core. That's still too slow. But (talking above my pay grade here)
perhaps there is a way to store all the values I need in a C structure that "fits on the stack" and then I wouldn't have to fetch the values from slower memory. This seems too low-level for me, but I'm willing to learn if I had an example.

BTW, I profiled this in Instruments and `[NSCFSet member:]` takes up
86.6% percent of the CPU time.

Then I thought I should extract all the durations into a sorted array so I would not have
to look up the duration value in the dictionary. I think that is a good
idea, but when I started to implement it, I wondered how to determine
the best batch size.

If I have the following durations:

```
    2 2 3 4 5 6 6 16 17 38 59   Duration
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6  7  8  9 10   Index
```

Then just by iterating over the array, I know that to find matching
tracks of the song at index 0, I only need to compare it against songs
up to index 6. That's great, I have my first batch. But now I have to
start over at index 1 only to find that it's batch should also stop at
index 6 and exclude index 0. I'm assuming I'm wasting a lot of
processing cycles here determining what the batch should be/the duration
matches.  This seemed like a "set" problem, but we didn't do much of
that in my Intro to Algorithms class.

My questions are:

1) What is the most efficient way to identify matching tracks? Is it
something similar to what's above? Is it using disjoint and [unified]
set operations that are slightly above my knowledge level? Is it
filtering arrays using NSArray? Is there an online resource that
describes this problem and solution?

I am willing to restructure the tracks dictionary in whatever way
(datastructure) is most efficient. I had at first thought I needed to
perform many lookups by TrackID, but that is no longer the case.

2) Is there a more efficient way to approach this problem? How do you
rock stars go from paragraph 1 to an optimized solution?

I have searched for the answer, longer than I care to admit, and found
these interesting, but unhelpful answers:

[find duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373588/find-duplicates/4373719#4373719)

[Find all duplicates and missing values in a sorted array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590109/find-all-duplicates-and-missing-values-in-a-sorted-array/590133#590133)

Thanks for any help you can provide,
Lance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is to maintain some sorted collections as indices into your dictionary so you can stop doing an O(n^2) search comparing every track to every other track.

If you had arrays of TrackIDs sorted by duration then for any track you could do a more efficient O(log n) binary search to find tracks with durations within your 5 second tolerance.

Even better for artist and name you can store a dictionary keyed on the artist or track name whose values are arrays of TrackIDs. Then you only need a O(1) lookup to get the set of tracks for a particular artist which should allow you to very quickly determine if there are any  possible duplicates.

Finally if you've built that sort of dictionary of titles to TrackIDs then you can go through all of it's keys and only search for duplicates when there are multiple tracks with the same title. Doing further comparisons only when there are multiple tracks with the same title should eliminate a significant percentage of the library and massively reduce your search time (down to O(n) to build the dictionary and another O(n) for a worst case search for duplicates still leaves you at O(n) rather than the O(n^2) you have now).

---

If nothing else do that last optimization, the resulting performance increase should be huge for an library without a significant number of duplicates:

```
NSMutableArray *possibleDuplicates = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableDictionary *knownTitles = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSMutableDictionary *track in [tracks allKeys]) {
    if ([knownTitles objectForKey:[track objectForKey:@"title"]] != nil) {
        [possibleDuplicates addObject:track];
    }
    else {
        [knownTitles addObject:[track objectForKey:@"TrackID"] forKey:[track objectForKey:@"title"]];
    }
}
//check for duplicates of the tracks in possibleDuplicates only.
```

Comment: These are great suggestions Jonah. I'll code some of these this weekend and post results here.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, but here's my first naïve guess:

Have a mutable dictionary.
The keys in this dictionary are the names of the songs.
The value of each key is another mutable dictionary.
The keys of this secondary mutable dictionary are the artists.
The value of each key is a mutable array of songs.

You'd end up with something like this:

```
NSArray *songs = ...; //your array of songs
NSMutableDictionary *nameCache = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (Song *song in songs) {
  NSString *name = [song name];
  NSMutableDictionary *artistCache = [nameCache objectForKey:name];
  if (artistCache == nil) {
    artistCache = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [nameCache setObject:artistCache forKey:name];
  }

  NSString *artist = [song artist];
  NSMutableArray *songCache = [artistCache objectForKey:artist];
  if (songCache == nil) {
    songCache = [NSMutableArray array];
    [artistCache setObject:songCache forKey:artist];
  }

  for (Song *otherSong in songCache) {
    //these are songs that have the same name and artist
    NSTimeInterval myDuration = [song duration];
    NSTimeInterval otherDuration = [otherSong duration];
    if (fabs(myDuration - otherDuration) < 5.0f) {
      //name matches, artist matches, and their difference in duration is less than 5 seconds
    }
  }
  [songCache addObject:song];
}
```

This is a worst-case O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm (if every song has the same name, artist, and duration).  It's a best-case O(n) algorithm (if every song has a different name/artist/duration), and will realistically end up being closer to O(n) than to O(n<sup>2</sup>) (most likely).